# "assumed an expression appropriate to the sickbed of a close friend" meaning in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Mr Weasley gave a maniacal laugh; Mrs Weasley threw him a look, upon which he become immediately silent and **assumed an expression appropriate to the sickbed of a close friend**.
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows</sub>

I don't quite get the meaning of "*assumed an expression appropriate to the sickbed of a close friend*". What's it supposed to mean? The part confuses me most is "the sickbed of a close friend".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Assume" can mean *to take or begin to have* something. The most commonly used definition, perhaps the one you are more familiar with - *to make an assumption* - means to take on an idea, without perhaps the requisite thought or evidence.

In your context, it means that the person "took on" a facial expression.

Saying someone *assumed* an expression rather than just saying they *had* one carries the idea that they deliberately made the facial expression, that perhaps it did not just come naturally, and done "for show" because of the situation they were in - by someone's sickbed. If you were by someone's sickbed, you wouldn't smile, would you? You'd "assume" a sympathetic face, either naturally, if you genuinely felt empathy, otherwise, you'd just force it because it was "appropriate".

Comment: What about the part "the sickbed of a close friend"?

Comment: @dan If you were by someone's sickbed, you wouldn't smile, would you? You'd "assume" a sympathetic face, either naturally if you genuinely felt empathy, otherwise you'd just force it because it was "appropriate".

Comment: I feel it should be ***the sickbed of a close friend's***. Is there any difference between "the sickbed of a close friend" and "the sickbed of a close friend's"?

Comment: _The sickbed of a close friend's_ is not idiomatic. That "double possessive" is not normally used only with an indefinite article, introducing a new object (eg _A friend of my father's_). When it refers to a definite object, we use the normal possessive (_eg my father's friend').

Comment: @ColinFine so, "a sickbed of a close friend's" would be idiomatic?

Comment: @dan: No. I think this is because somebody only has at most one sickbed (at least, at any particular time), so _a sickbed of_ somebody is incoherent.